# oracle sql query hierarchicle query to find top level

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical

I have an oracle table that contains and ID column, and ID_child column, and several fact fields.  I know an ID and I want to find its top level parent.  The id I know would but put into the ID_child field and the ID would be its parent.
This query worked but I only get one row which I could do with a regular sql query.  **How do I get the top ID?**

```
SELECT
item_tbl.id, item_tbl.id_child
FROM item_tbl
START WITH item_tbl.id_child = 12510646
CONNECT BY PRIOR item_tbl.id_child = item_tbl.id
```

results I get:

```
ID               ID_CHILD
12512162         12510646
```

Comment: Reverse the connect by statements. you have: `CONNECT BY PRIOR item_tbl.id_child = item_tbl.id` change it to `CONNECT BY PRIOR = item_tbl.id =item_tbl.id_child`  In connect by; order matters!  you could add level and order by level descending to see parent to child or use other methods within connect by to see the path.

Comment: That worked** I reversed it and now I get each level to the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:
Order of the connect by matters; parent needs to be on the left side.

```
With item_tbl (ID, ID_CHILD) as 
(SELECT 1,2 from dual UNION ALL
SELECT 2,3 from dual UNION ALL
SELECT 3,4 from dual)
SELECT
item_tbl.id, item_tbl.id_child, level
FROM item_tbl
START WITH item_tbl.id_child = 4
CONNECT BY PRIOR item_tbl.id= item_tbl.id_child
Order by level desc;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help that worked.  I finally got a hierarchical query to give me results that I worked or I understood.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get the top ID?

You can use the `CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF` pseudocolumn:

```
SELECT id, id_child
FROM   item_tbl
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
START WITH id_child = 12510646
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = id_child
```

If that doesn't work then try swapping the terms in the `CONNECT BY` clause.